# VS 2008 - Objects disappearing?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs

I've only been using VS 2008 Team Foundation for a few weeks. Over the last few days, I've noticed that sometimes one of my objects/controls on my page just disappears from intellisense. The project builds perfectly and the objects are still in the HTML, but I still can't find the object.

Any one else notice this?

**Edit:** For what it's worth, I know if I close VS and then open it up again, it comes back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also having a number of problems with VS 2008.  Who would guess that I don't ever need to select multiple controls on a web form...

Anyway, a lot has been fixed in Service Pack 1, which is in Beta currently.  Might be worth installing that.  It has gone a little way to fixing absolute positioning.  This isn't your problem, of course, but your fix might be in there as well.

Answer (score 3):

The [Visual Studio 2008 and .NET 3.5 Framework Service Pack 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/products/cc533447.aspx) has gone out of beta, maybe you can see if this bug still occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally get this in Visual Studio 2005.

A method I use to get the controls back, is to switch the web page between code view and design view. I know it's not a fix but it's a little quicker than restarting Visual Studio.